# Creating an array that multiplies and adds its elements in all unique possible combinations

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, math

I am currently working on a project for calculating polynomial shifts via python of nth degree.
The user can input n amount of inputs which get stored in an array that then get converted via the shift and turned back into a new polynomial. The problem is, the higher the degree of n, the more calculations necessary to turn the shifted value to it's polynomial coefficient:

What the program should do is add and multiply all the values uniquely and save the result in a new array:

e.g. for a polynomial of degree 4, it will have inputs [a,b,c,d]

```
shiftedPCL[0] = a + b + c + d
shiftedPCL[1] = a*b + b*c + c*d + a*c + b*d + a*d
shiftedPCL[2] = a*b*c + b*c*d + a*b*d + a*c*d
shiftedPCL[3] = a*b*c*d
```

The first and last lines of the equations can be solved simply by summing and multiplying all the values in a list respectively, and I have created a simple recursive code to calculate the second to last line of equations using recursion, but for n greater than 3 it is useless, as it cannot calculate any lines that aren't the first, last or second to last.

This is why I would like to know if there's a way to add and multiply all elements in a list as shown above (for lists of any length).

Comment: I don' think that what you describe is a polynomial shift.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in my opinion would be using python itertool. Python itertool is a module that provides various functions that work on iterators to produce complex iterators. The function is itertools permutations. This might be the easiest though slowest program:

```
from itertools import permutations
list1 = [1,2,3,4] #replace with a, b, c and d
shiftedPCL = []
for i in range(1,len(list1)+1):
    comb = permutations(list1, i)
    sum1 = 0
    for j in comb:
        print(j)
        result = 1
        for x in j:
            result = result * x
        sum1 += result
    shiftedPCL.append(sum1)

print(shiftedPCL)
```

Variable Names changed as recommended by @Stef

Comment: Please do not recommend naming variables `list` or `sum`. Those are already the names of builtins in python. Shadowing a builtin is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Stef Will keep that in mind thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is the expansion of a product of monic binomials like

```
(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d) = x^4 + Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D.
```

Don't do that by means of the (modified) Vieta's formulas. Instead, apply *one binomial at a time*.

E.g. after three factors already expanded,

```
(x^3 + Px^2 + Qx + R)(x + d) = x^4 + (P + d) x^3 + (Q + Pd) x^2 + (R + Qd) x + Rd.
```

Answer (score 0):

The element at index `i` in your resulting array is the sum of all products of combinations of `i` elements.

In python, the sum of all products of combinations of `i` elements from a list `l` can be written as:

```py
sum(map(prod, combinations(l,i)))
```

Where `sum` and `map` are [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), and `prod` and `combinations` are imported from standard library modules [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), respectively.

```py
from itertools import combinations
from math import prod

def sums_of_products(l):
    return [sum(map(prod, combinations(l,i))) for i in range(1, len(l)+1)]
```

We can test this function with numbers, or with symbols using sympy:

```py
from sympy import symbols

a,b,c,d = symbols('a b c d')
print( sums_of_products([a,b,c,d]) )
# [a + b + c + d,
#  a*b + a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d + c*d,
#  a*b*c + a*b*d + a*c*d + b*c*d,
#  a*b*c*d]

print( sums_of_products([2,3,5,7]) )
# [17, 101, 247, 210]
```